# What is /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base and /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/base folders?

Tags: document-classes, linux

What is `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base` and `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/base` folders?  What's this folders used for?

**Additional information I want**

How can I make my own document classes by creating files in this folders? What can I make using this folders?

Comment: these folders contain the base files of the latex format, and you shouldn't put anything in them (actually you shouldn't put anything in the whole texmf-dist). If you want to add your own files, put them e.g. in `texmf-local/tex/latex`